# How to write this iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

I want estimate the strategy I make:
buy- where the K_Class is 1
sell- where the K_Class is 0
all  prices is refered to Close Column at the time

for example:
Suppose that I have the amount of money 10000, the first time I buy is 2017/03/13, the first time I sell is 2017/03/17. The second time I buy is 2017/03/20, the second time I sell is on 2017/03/22

My Question: Till the end, how do I calculate the amount of money?

```
 Time        Close        K_Class
    0     2017/03/06  31.72        0
    1     2017/03/08  33.99        0
    2     2017/03/09  32.02        0
    3     2017/03/10  30.66        0
    4     2017/03/13  30.94        1
    5     2017/03/15  32.56        1
    6     2017/03/17  33.31        0
    7     2017/03/20  34.07        1
    8     2017/03/22  34.40        0
    9     2017/03/24  32.98        1
    10    2017/03/27  33.26        0
    11    2017/03/28  31.60        0
    12    2017/03/29  30.36        0
    13    2017/03/30  28.83        0
    14    2017/04/11  27.01        0
    15    2017/04/12  24.31        0
    16    2017/04/14  24.22        0
    17    2017/04/17  21.80        0
    18    2017/04/18  21.20        1
    19    2017/04/19  23.32        1
    20    2017/04/20  24.43        0
    21    2017/04/24  23.85        1
    22    2017/04/26  23.97        1
    23    2017/04/27  24.31        1
    24    2017/04/28  23.50        1
    25    2017/05/02  22.57        1
    26    2017/05/03  22.67        1
    27    2017/05/04  22.11        1
    28    2017/05/05  21.26        1
    29    2017/05/08  19.37        1
    ..           ...    ...      ...
    275   2018/08/01  13.38        0
    276   2018/08/03  12.49        0
    277   2018/08/06  12.50        0
    278   2018/08/07  12.78        0
    279   2018/08/09  12.93        0
    280   2018/08/10  13.15        0
    281   2018/08/13  13.14        1
    282   2018/08/14  13.15        0
    283   2018/08/15  12.80        0
    284   2018/08/17  12.29        0
    285   2018/08/21  12.39        0
    286   2018/08/22  12.15        0
    287   2018/08/23  12.27        0
    288   2018/08/24  12.31        0
    289   2018/08/27  12.47        0
    290   2018/08/29  12.31        0
    291   2018/08/30  12.13        0
    292   2018/08/31  11.69        0
    293   2018/09/03  11.60        1
    294   2018/09/04  11.65        0
    295   2018/09/05  11.45        0
    296   2018/09/07  11.42        0
    297   2018/09/10  10.71        0
    298   2018/09/11  10.76        1
    299   2018/09/12  10.74        0
    300   2018/09/13  10.85        1
    301   2018/09/14  10.79        0
    302   2018/09/18  10.58        1
    303   2018/09/19  10.65        1
    304   2018/09/21  10.73        1
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit more. What do you mean by `invest money` and `invest time`, how many shares of stock do you buy each time, is short allowed, and most importantly, what effort have you put into this?

Comment: I have edited a little bit to make it simplier, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':np.arange(10), 'class':np.random.randint(2, size=10)})
df['diff'] = -1 * df['class'].diff()
df.loc[0,['diff']] = -1 * df.loc[0,['class']].values
df['money'] = df['price']*df['diff']
```

so the 'diff' represent the buy and sell action (-1 for buy and +1 for sell). The product of it and the price gives the changes of money you have. Sum it up, plus your initial money, you'll get your final money.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['diff'] = df['K_Class'].diff()

stock_sell = 0
current_amount = 10000
for n in range(0, df.index.size-1):
    print(n)
    if df.iloc[n, 10] == 1:
        stock_sell = current_amount/df.iloc[n, 4]
    if df.iloc[n, 10] == -1:
        current_amount = stock_sell*df.iloc[n, 4]
print(current_amount)
```